# springboot upgrade from 2.5.6 to 2.6.6 issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@Configuration
public class A {
@Autowired
 private Integer connectTimeOut;
    @Bean
    public Integer connectTimeOut(){
        return getTimeOutConfigured(HTTP_CONNECT_TIME_OUT, -1);
    }
}
```

Springboot can't start successfully with below issue:
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

```
┌──->──┐
|  A (field private java.lang.Integer XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX.XXX.A.connectTimeOut)
└──<-──┘
```

It can work fine from springboot 2.5.6. But it can't start for 2.6.6.

Any one who has the experience? or any advice?

Comment: I doubt that that is the full class and that is a dumbed down version. If you want help please post the actual code. Also making an `Integer` a bean is probably a bad ting already, it should be an `@Value`. The problem is that your bean is named `connectTimeout` and you are wiring it into the same class, which leads to a circular dependency. Why are you even wiring it into the same class.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using this `connectTimeOut` value somewhere, probably in some other bean:

```
public class MyBean {
   private final Integer connectTimeOut;
   public MyBean(Integer connectTimeOut) {
      this.connectTimeOut = connectTimeOut;
   }
}
```

And your configuration class looks something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class A {
@Autowired
 private Integer connectTimeOut;
    @Bean
    public Integer connectTimeOut(){
        return getTimeOutConfigured(HTTP_CONNECT_TIME_OUT, -1);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean(connectTimeOut);
    }
}
```

If so, consider using the built-in mechanism of spring boot to work with configuration properties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyConfigProperties{
   private Integer connectTimeOut = -1; // default
   // setter, getter, no-args-constructor
}
```

In `application.yml` or properties file define:

`application.yml`

```
connectTimeOut: 30
```

Now you can rewrite the configuration and get rid of the autowiring altogether:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfigProperties.class)
public class A {

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean(MyConfigProperties config) { // Injecting the configuration!!!
        return new MyBean(config.getConnectTimeOut());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A cycle would explain why it worked in 2.5 but not in 2.6. The [Spring Boot 2.6 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes/8be732ac54b39274e2bdb43dfce559496c9d1bd8#circular-references-prohibited-by-default) describe what's going on and how to resolve the issue:

> Circular references between beans are now prohibited by default. If your application fails to start due to a BeanCurrentlyInCreationException you are strongly encouraged to update your configuration to break the dependency cycle. If you are unable to do so, circular references can be allowed again by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true, or using the new setter methods on SpringApplication and SpringApplicationBuilder This will restore 2.5’s behaviour and automatically attempt to break the dependency cycle.